# Controller as with directive not working

Tags: angularjs

I want to accomplish scroll-able content by clicking on Bootstrap module. Its working fine. This is following code of my directive:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('cbookApp')
        .directive('scrollTo', scrollTo);

scrollTo.$inject = ['$anchorScroll'];
function scrollTo($anchorScroll) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                var location = attrs.scrollTo;
                if (scope.vm.isEdit || typeof scope.vm.isEdit =="undefined" ) { 
                    $anchorScroll(location);
                } else {
                    $anchorScroll(location+'1');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

But only problem is i am not sure how to apply active class to current affix `li`. This [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hngzxmda/) way i found to apply class `active` to current `li` and remove from other. It was working without `Controller as` but once i added controller as it stopped working and give some error of scope.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['directives']);
app.controller('firstController',[function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.model = { value: 'dsf'};
}]);
angular.module('directives', []).directive('toggleClass', function () {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span ng-click="localFunction()" ng-class="selected"  ng-transclude></span>',
        replace: true,
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.localFunction = function () {
                scope.model.value = scope.$id;
            };
            scope.$watch('model.value', function () {
                if (scope.model.value === scope.$id) {
                    scope.selected = "active";
                } else {
                    scope.selected = '';
                }
            });
        }
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

Comment: I think you are now half way between the old way and the new way. I'd start by using `bindToController: {model: '='}, scope: {},`

Comment: @SimonH Yes may be. But this much information is not enough.

Comment: If you create a plnkr, happy to work on it

Comment: @SimonH i have given link of `JsFiddle` which is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/hngzxmda/

Answer (score 2):

Can you please add this in your directive.

```
element.parent().parent().children().each(function() {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
});
element.addClass('active');
```

Comment: Yes this is working but, Is this correct way to do this(Iterating each element)? With javascript i have replaced `$(this).find('a').removeClass('active');` line with `angular.element(this.querySelector('a')).removeClass('active');`. I am curious to know why my way is not working.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hngzxmda/1/

I suggest using controllerAs in your directive too

```
angular.module('directives', []).directive('toggleClass', function () {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span ng-click="vmd.localFunction()" ng-class="selected"  ng-transclude></span>',
        replace: true,
        bindToController: {
            model: '=',
            $id: '='
        },
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        controller: function() {
            var _this = this;
            this.localFunction = function () {
                _this.model.value = _this.$id;
            };
        },
        controllerAs: 'vmd'
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```